# I literally got stuck of the explanation of Quotient map

Tags: general-topology, definition

I literally got stuck of the explanation of **Quotient map** in the book **Topology by Munkres** when it comes to the explanation using ***Saturation***.

Can anyone please refer another book where I can get a explanation (using ***Saturation***), and explained easily!!

I got stuck since the book says this:

[image: Saturation]

It says $C$ is complete inverse image of $Y$. $\color{red}{\text{Then $C=X$ isn't! What am I missing here}}$.

Comment: Note that it says "the complete inverse image of a subset of Y"; that is, $C=p^{-1}(A)$ for some $A\subseteq Y$.

Comment: I wasted at least 5 hrs, and missed the word "subset"(ha ha) ... thanks @JohnGriffin

Answer (score 1):

I read through the whole Chapter on 'The Quotient Topology' in Munkres and understood absolutely nothing, it was only when I read about the Quotient Topology in *John Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds* that I finally grasped the concepts. (It is a delight to read)

So with regards to your request for another book reference, I would recommend that book, which goes pretty in depth on some of the topic related to the Quotient Topology and Quotient Spaces.

Comment: Thankssssss, I am at the last page of the section of *The Quotient Topology*, it took two days to come here... but it is really tough to see every steps and grasping it with full confidence!!! Thanks for the reference, I am going to look into it right now!!!

Comment: No problem! @MANMAID